# Is there any meta data attributes for tags to Google Crawlers

Tags: html, seo

I ***not*** asking `<meta>` tag but attributes which give more meaningful insights to Google Crawler.

For example:

Since neither `<datetime>` nor `<time>` is supported for most of the major browsers, it would be better to have such an attribute `semantic:type='datetime'` for a `<span>` element.

```
<span id='time' semantic:type='datetime'>12-10-2011</span>
```

Are there any such attributes?

And I hope these techniques help me to optimize my website better for search engines crawlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [microformats](http://schema.org/). There's [a lot of specific one](http://schema.org/docs/full.html)s you can use depending on the data to be marked up.

Comment: This seems what I am looking for.